# Change margin of an existing div class (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="name">bs</div>
```

With a margin-right set to 30px. How can i change it to 10px?

Comment: What browser are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(reference to your div).style.marginRight = 10+'px';
```

Answer (score -3):

I do not like applying styles inline. I'd add a utility class.

```
$("element_id").addClass("utilityClassname");
```

Comment: There is nothing mentioned about jQuery in the question.

Comment: Neither does it solve the OP's problem